# UITextField with the lookup

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I would like to achive the same functinoanlity in the UITextField control as Google search web site (which uses Ajax for this): as user start typing, list of suggestion searches is shown. Then more letteres you type, suggestion list changes.

So imaging I have array of words:

1. Apple
2. Abc
3. Aman

As user types A, all thress suggesions are shown, if user type one more letter p, then Apple is suggested.

How would I do something like this? Mail type of applicatins do it, when receipent name is typed in the To: edit control

I guess I can use UITableView with the search, is it correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a UISearchBar. It's designed to do exactly this. Its delegate provides the list to search and present.

Comment: Cool. Yes, this what I ended up using - UISearchBar with the included delegate.
Is there a way to add to the left component of the UISplitView for iPad (not the detail view)?
thanks

Comment: I haven't done it but I don't think it should be an issue. It can generate its own table to show its results